# Compare two lists from two attributes and add differences to the third list C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-core

I need to compare two lists using two parameters of a class (same class) and add the difference to a third class. The `Except()` don't work for my situation.

I'm thinking of something like that, comparing XXX to YYY from another list:

```
var newList = List1.Select(x => x.XXX && x.YYY)
      .Except(List2.Select(x => x.XXX && x.YYY));
```

thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linq Query To Combine 2 Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930288/linq-query-to-combine-2-lists)

Comment: or maybe https://stackoverflow.com/q/23016768/125981

Comment: or https://stackoverflow.com/q/720609/125981 - many answers like this to choose from

Comment: Care to elaborate why `Except` wont work but you then propose using `Except`  on projections of the original lists as a viable option? You are aware you can pass in an `IEqualityComoparer<T>` tailored to your specific needs when calling `Excecpt`, right? Maybe including a real example with similar data of your problem can help.

Comment: Note this may also be that you need a not contains like this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/7348099/125981

Answer (score 2):

Your current way can only get different data that exists in List1 but not in List2.

To get all their different data, you also need to `reverse except` and merge them by `Union`.

Here is my class Product:

```
public class Product
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }  
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
        }
```

Here is the code:

```
  List<Product> List1 = new List<Product>()
        {
            new Product(){   Id =1, Title="aaa", Description="cccccccc" },
             new Product(){  Id =2,Title="bbb", Description="cccccccc" },
              new Product(){  Id =3, Title="ccc", Description="cccccccc"  },
        };
        List<Product> List2 = new List<Product>()
        {
            new Product(){  Id =1, Title="aaa" , Description ="csdfsdf"},
             new Product(){  Id =4, Title="bbb" , Description ="cccccccccc"},
        };
        var newList= (List1.Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Title }).Except(List2.Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Title })).
            Union(List2.Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Title }).Except(List1.Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Title })))).ToList();
```

Here is the test process:

[image]